# Javafx gridpane layout allignment

Tags: java, layout, javafx, javafx-2, gridpane

I have a small question.
I am trying to create a good GUI (which you can resize) with JavaFX 2.0 but I have a small problem.
I am using a gridpane but when i put multiple buttons in it and when I resize the screen to a smaller size the buttons will slide into each other at the left size of the screen.
Can I set a minimum size for a cell or something, I am using an FXML for the design.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the minimum width of a column by specifying a set of `ColumnConstraints` objects on the `GridPane`.

For example, something like:

```
<GridPane hgap"5" vgap="5">
<Label text="First Name:" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
<TextField GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

<Label text="Last Name:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
<TextField GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints minWidth="100" halignment="RIGHT" />
<ColumnConstraints minWidth="150" halignment="LEFT" />
</columnConstraints>

</GridPane>
```

You can similarly control the layout of the rows, if desired.

See the Javadocs for [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) and [ColumnConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) to see other properties that can be controlled this way.